# Where to write data for web server www-data user

Tags: webserver, cgi, lighttpd, picamera

I have a web server on a Pi with a Pi Camera. The goal is to click a button on a web page and have the camera take a picture and save it through a script in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`. Then I want to retrieve all of the pictures via ftp. This works, but I don't think I set up the permissions well. I gave `www-data` write access to a folder in the `pi` user's home directory, so it can save the pictures.

While this works, it seems sloppy and insecure. Should I be saving the files in a different location? I would still need to access them via ftp.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/lib/$progname` is usually a good place to save data by (system) programs. You could also choose the webserver's directory, e.g. `/var/www/...` (depending on your configuration and version in place).